# What is the best way to I get started learning Azure mobile services?

Tags: iphone, azure, mobile

I am new to Azure and I need to create a mobile service for my iPhone app. How can I get up to speed quickly?

Comment: This question is legit. Microsoft has actually tutorial designed for this specific scenario:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-ios-get-started/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created a set of labs that walk the user through the basics of Azure Mobile Services. You can download them from https://github.com/DavidGiard/Azure-Mobile-Services-Labs